# Fatal error when updating joomla from 3.1.1 to 3.2.2

Tags: joomla3.0

I updated my joomla site from 3.1.1 to 3.2.2 but now when I view my site I get

Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/studentw/public_html/plugins/system/remember/remember.php on line 96

I tried restoring my directory from a back up but I am still getting the error above.  Line 96 of the remember.php file is:

```
$this->cookie_domain = $this->app->get('cookie_domain', '');
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is your friend:

> Rename your file remember.php to rememberBAK.php so it looks like this
>   /plugins/system/remember/rememberBAK.php
>   Find a copy of Joomla 3.1.15 and make a copy of the remember.php.
>   FTP the file to your folder
>   /plugins/system/remember/remember.php.
>   Now access your admin panel:
>   Go to Extensions -> Extension Manage -> Database.
>   Click Fix.
>   Now go to ftp, delete the remember.php that you uploaded and rename the original one to it's correct state.
>   Joomla updates do not update the database and this needs to be done manually.
>   For not developers, the above method is the simplest and quickest way

Source:[Upgrade from 3.1 to 3.2 Fatal Error in Administrator Page](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=710&t=825407#p3103165)