# Errors while upgrading joomla 2.5 to 3.x.x

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I attempted to upgrade from joomla 2.5.11 to 3.2.3 which is latest right now. First of all I checked and upgraded all extensions - **CB, k2, kunena, xmap** (I did not upgrade xmap as I  got errors so I left it, little one not important) to latest by going `extensions manager -> update tab`. Then going `components-> joomla-> update` update to **3.2.3.** The update finished but I got an error about `remember.php` and could not access admin panel.

Getting suggestions from  [Fatal error when updating joomla from 3.1.1 to 3.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689666/fatal-error-when-updating-joomla-from-3-1-1-to-3-2-2) , I uploaded a **joomla 3.2.3** package's `remember.php` file in `/plugins/system/remember/` folder backing up previous file.

But I got another error -

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method RuntimeException::get() in
>   /home/techhe97/public_html/libraries/joomla/error/error.php on line
>   797

So, can't access admin panel all the way.

Comment: Try first updating to Joomla 2.5.19 (latest version of the 2.5 series), and then migrating to Joomla 3.2.3

Comment: why 2.5 version should be latest ? any thoughts? i will try it to my local computer installation under xampp.

Comment: Yes i followed your idea locally but still problem persists.I downloaded upgrade package from joomla.org and upgraded but still same errors, that's why can't access admin panel.Why so much errors should be ?? for extensions?