# Understanding about some tables when doing database migration to joomla upper version

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0, joomla-k2

I attempted to upgrade joomla from 2.5.x versions to 3 versions but got various errors like as the one i posted here before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940409/errors-while-upgrading-joomla-2-5-to-3-x-x).
So i am trying another way by moving database tables from 2.5.11 to 3.2.3 version database.So for this i installed a new 3.2.3 site with required extensions like k2, CB...

i have been able to move joomla 2.5.11 site's database tables like users, modules, menus and other extension tables to joomla 3.2.3 site so is in this new site i am getting all users and menus and modules and extension's data.

> But what about the "assets" and "extensions" tables, to do a complete
>   upgrade by database, should i move these two tables for
>   compatibilities with other things in new site? or i am done leaving
>   these tables well?.

Fyi, in my 2.5.11 site i don't need content articles as i am using k2.Furthermore, what other required tables' data i must move to new site for a complete migration using database tables?

Comment: Are you moving the table data using SQL scripts or PHP?

Comment: This exponentially increases the difficulty of what you're trying to accomplish.  Joomla's ACL depends heavily on the assets table and there is a lot of automated correlations established when creating content and categories of any type in the administrators interface.  Whenever I'm faced with migrating a website I always used PHP and the Joomla framework to connect directly to the old database and use the core JTable classes for categories, articles, modules, menus, etc to create the new entries as all of those associations are automated.

Comment: If that is not an option, you will need to dig into the respective JTable extended classes for each of the tables in question to figure out and manually script the required edits to all tables using sql scripts.

Comment: It's look like bit hard job to add/edit tables in destination site database using php code and JTable classes when dealing with assets table only.Have u got any tutorials specific to this?. The way i do all stuffs by sql scripts is much fruitful, as i put drop table sql commands for all required tables and then put create table commands and then insert data sql commands from source 2.5 site's required tables in sql script and finally run it in destination database.If some columns missing, i click fix in extension manager-> database page, and things pretty wroking.

Comment: It could be a matter of strength, I'm a much stronger PHP programmer and Joomla developer then I am at scripting SQL.  Since it appears from your comment the sql scripts are working pretty well.  Regarding the extensions table, this holds both core and third party extensions.  You simply need to be mindful of the fact any 3rd party extensions will be expecting the files on the new site, and sometimes there are changes to file structure and custom tables between the same extension for different versions of Joomla.  If the sql scripting is working, stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you install a clean 3.2.3, then install all of the extensions you need, then the assets and extensions tables do not need to be touched. You only need to move the tables that include content from the old site.

Comment: What about weblinks entries.i saw there is a row for a weblinks category in 2.5 assets table and might there be any relation between content and assets tables?

Comment: Did you have any weblinks on the old site? If not, then no need to mess with it. There will be a record in the assets table for weblinks since I believe that weblinks also use standard Joomla categories.

Comment: Yes i have couple of weblinks which is ignorable.Although leaving assets table ignoring those ACL rules is not a headache, but when site have lots of articles, categories, weblinks then i might have to deal with assets table.